# Perl - Search for specific string in csv and extract characters that immediately follow it

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, csv

I have a csv file that has 2 columns: an ID and a free text columns.  The ID column contains a 16-character alphanumeric id but it may not be the only data present in the cell: it may be a blank cell, or a cell that contains only the 16-character id, or contain a bunch of stuff along with the following buried in it - "user_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

What I want is to somehow extract the 16-character id from whichever cells have it.  So I need to:
(a) ignore blank cells
(b) extract the whole cell's content if all it has is a continuous 16-character string with no spaces in between
(c) look for the pattern "user_id=" and then extract the 16 characters that immediately follow it

I see a lot of Perl scripts for either pattern matching or find/replace string etc., but I am not sure how I can do different kinds of parsing/pattern searching and extraction one after the other on the same column.  As you may have already realized, I am fairly new to Perl.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to (1) skip lines that contain nothing, or that fail to match your spec.  (2) Capture 16 non-space characters if they are the only content of the cell.  (3) Capture 16 non-space characters following the literal pattern "user_id=".

If it's ok to capture space characters too, if they follow a "`user_id=`" literal, you can change `\S` to `.` in the appropriate place.

My solution uses [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) to handle the details of dealing with a CSV file.  Here's how you might do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use Text::CSV;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( {binary => 1} ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag;

while( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    my $column = $row->[0];
    if( $column =~ m/^(\S{16})$/ || $column =~ m/user_id=(\S{16})/ ) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
abcdefghijklmnop
user_id=abcdefghijklmnop
abcd fghij lmnop
randomdatAuser_id=abcdefghijklmnopMorerandomdata
user_id=abcd fghij lmnop
randomdatAuser_id=abcd fghij lmnopMorerandomdata
```

In your own code you would not be using the `DATA` filehandle, but I assume you know how to [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file already.

CSV is a format that is deceptively simple.  Don't confuse its high readability with parsing simplicity though.  When dealing with CSV, it's best to use a well-proven module to extract the columns.  Other solutions can fail quote-embedded commas, escaped commas, unbalanced quotes, and other irregularities that our brain fixes for us on the fly, but that make a pure-regex solution fragile.

Comment: @user1521736 Just following up a couple weeks later to check and see if this response (or one of the others) was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can set you up with a basic file and regex commands that might do what you need (in a sorta basic format for someone not familiar with perl):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE "<:utf8", "myfile.csv";
#"slurp" the file into an array, each element is a line
my @lines = <FILE>;
my @idArray;
foreach my $line (@lines){
    #make two captures, the first we can ignore and both are optional
    $line =~ /^(user_id=|)([A-Za-z0-9]{16}|),/;
    #for display purposes, this is just the second captured group
    my $id = $2;
    #if the group actually has something in it, add it to your final array
    if($id){ push @idArray, $id; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, in the next example only line 2 and 3 is valid, so in the cell1 (column1) is

- string what is exactly 16 chars long, or
- has the "user=16charshere"

Any other is not valid.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($col1, @remainder) = split /\t/;
    say $2 if $col1 =~ m/^(|user=)(.{16})$/;
}
__DATA__
ToShort col2    not_valid
a123456789012345    col2    valid
user=b123456789012345   col2    valid
TooLongStringHereSoNotValidOne  col2    not_valid
```

In this example the columns are TAB separated.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide (a) some example data which can be used for testing solutions and (b) please try supplying code you have written so far for this problem.

However, you will probably want to go through all rows of your table, then `split` it into fields, performe all your operations on a certain field, perform business logic, and then write everything back.

Problem (c) is solved by `$idField =~ /user_id=(.{16})/; my $id = $1;`

If the user_id always appears at the beginning of a line, this does the trick: `for (<FILE>) {/^user_id=(.{16})/; ...}`